# How to add a custom CSS for a predefined report in GnuCash?

Tags: gnucash, balance-sheet

I'd like to add a CSS stylesheet to the default "Balance Sheet" report.
I made the CSS changes as [the documentation](https://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) says, but I found no way to actually use my CSS during report generation.

How am I supposed to do that?

OS: Linux, Arch

Answer (score 0):

Follow https://www.gnucash.org/docs/v4/C/gnucash-help/change-style.html to manage style sheets. If you want more styles than those available through the gui you will need to edit the css file yourself.

Open a report and there will be an options button. Select Options, General, Stylesheet then select the stylesheet you want to use with the report.